# System.Diagnostics.Process not properly closing after the application is closed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, process, .net-4.8

I have been trying to find a solution to why the [ExitTool](https://exiftool.org/) I am using is not properly closing out after I close the main application. What is happening is that when I close my application, the ExifTool stays running in the background and I have to manually kill it.

[image]

---

Here is the code snippet of the process startup.

```
Public Shared Sub ExecuteExifTool()
    If ExifToolStarted Then Exit Sub
    ExifToolStarted = True
    Dim NowString As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(".\Runtime") Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(".\Runtime")
    Dim GetDirectory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(".\Runtime")
    If GetDirectory.GetFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For Each i As IO.FileInfo In GetDirectory.GetFiles
            If i.FullName.Contains("exif.Yv") AndAlso i.FullName.Contains("-cL") AndAlso i.FullName.Contains(".exe") Then : Try : i.Delete() : Catch : End Try : End If
        Next
    End If
    HostName = ".\Runtime\exif.Yv" & NowString.Substring(0, 8) & "-cL" & NowString.Substring(8, 6) & ".exe"
    IO.File.Copy(".\exiftool.exe", HostName)
    Using ExifToolProcess As New Process
        With ExifToolProcess
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            .StartInfo.FileName = HostName
            .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            .StartInfo.Arguments = "-stay_open" & " True -@ " & "-"
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            .StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            .Start()
            .BeginOutputReadLine()
            .BeginErrorReadLine()
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

---

The latest attempt to solve this issue was to try and launch another executable application; which essentially, is another `Windows.Forms.Form` that waits for the main application to close and then it will attempt to kill the process immediately afterwards, then dispose of itself. Here is the snippet.

```
Public Class KillProcess

    Private _ProcessName As String
    Public Property ProcessName As String
        Get
            Return _ProcessName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ProcessName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _MainApp As Form
    Public Property MainApplication As Form
        Get
            Return _MainApp
        End Get
        Set(value As Form)
            _MainApp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub KillProcess_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CleanupProcess()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CleanupProcess()
        While Not MainApplication.IsDisposed
            Dim FilesToDelete As New List(Of String)
            Dim ProcessesToKill As New List(Of Process)
            For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
                If p.ProcessName = ProcessName Then
                    FilesToDelete.Add(p.MainModule.FileName)
                    ProcessesToKill.Add(p)
                End If
            Next
            For Each p As Process In ProcessesToKill
                Try
                    p.Kill()
                    p.WaitForExit(10000)
                    p.Close()
                Catch winException As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
                Catch invalidException As InvalidOperationException
                End Try
            Next
        End While
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

And here is the code snippet of the startup.

```
Public Sub CleanupTask()
    Dim Handler As New Custodian.KillProcess With {.ProcessName = ExifToolHooker.HostName, .MainApplication = Me}
    Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Handler)
End Sub

Private Sub CloseApplication(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Dim TaskHandler As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf CleanupTask)
    TaskHandler.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    TaskHandler.Start()
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: A possible problem is redirecting the standard output end error streams but not reading from them. If you don't need the program output, set `RedirectStandardInput`,  `RedirectStandardOutput` and `RedirectStandardError` to false. If you need the output, put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: As @Steeeve mentioned, it's not clear what you're actually doing there. It appears you're trying to handle asynchronously the Process output, but you have `Using ExifToolProcess As New Process` and nowhere you're adding the required event handlers. -- See the example shown here (VB.Net): [Process.Start() an executable and return a DialogResult to the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789279/7444103) and [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103) -- Assuming you want to read the output of that Process.

Comment: Steeeve & Jimi thank you both. I looked into redirecting from standard output more to make sure I didn't misunderstand/misinterpret what does. It turns out that I didn't need it at all and I was able I modified the code and now everything is working perfectly.